Why Does Blowfish Harm the Solana Blockchain?
I'm a solo developer on the Solana blockchain. Like many others, I've encountered the issue of Blowfish flagging my transactions as suspicious. To execute these transactions through Phantom or Backpack wallets, I have to bypass three warning windows that clearly state the transaction is malicious, hiding the proceed button behind several large elements that send the user back.
This practice is quite strange, so I contacted them via email for clarification. The method they proposed, signAndSendTransaction, doesn't work at all, which says a lot.
Additionally, the concept of endorsements that Blowfish offers as a solution is unclear to me. I don't use Twitter and have never sought friends or active mentors within the network, so I can't integrate into the community. Hence, my questions are:
Since when did Blowfish's activity of blocking developers become normal?
Why does the concept of cronyism take precedence in a decentralized network?
Why can't I develop as a developer under the guise of security and must be friends with the "right" people?
Finally, how can I bypass these flags without connections, and why do they exist if they can be bought?

Without inserting too much opinion:
This situation isn't entirely on Blowfish, as they are simply a service provider helping wallets flag transactions and domains. The way they handle domain flagging certainly leaves much to be desired, but this is not done with bad faith.
Wallet providers are in a tough place, because if there's no warnings then they get endless support tickets from users who get scammed. Blowfish stepped in to help mitigate these issues for wallet providers, and while that method is suboptimal for smaller developers, it is not done out of malice.
Ultimately, having centralized entities as the arbiters of app safety clearly isn't ideal in many situations on a decentralized blockchain, but it's what we've got for now.

Yes, the system is not perfect, and it is clear that this was done without malicious intent. The fact is that this does not solve the problem but creates many new ones, which can significantly impact the blockchain in the future. And I am not talking about positive changes.

Due to the lack of specific requirements regulating this issue, Solana is becoming unfriendly towards developers without connections. What we are seeing now does not reduce the amount of fraud; the same shitcoins die every day, and this does not prevent them from seizing others' funds.

I am also a solo dev going through issues because of their service. I reached out to them and they wanted me to prove I am legit by having some recognized influencer/dev vouch for me. I don't have those kinds of connection so I responded to them saying just that and they stopped responding to me. My app basically just converts SOL to WSOL and charges a miniscule fee. I admit my domain age is fairly new and that could be the reason but their warning is turning people away. I only current have the issue with phantom. This wasn't always the case so I am thoroughly disappointed. Bliwfishxzy is harming smaller devs in my opinion.

Totally agree I’m now facing the same issue.  I hope the recent acquisition by phantom will resolve their more than inadequate approval process.
